# 90s cartoon, caveman in search of monster eggs that he revives into talking creatures that can evolve when endangered

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, cartoon

Can't remember the name of a cartoon that aired in the mid-late 90s in the UK (maybe elsewhere as well).

It involved a time travelling... Buggy manned by a caveman, who went in search of monster... eggs in each episode. He'd then use this hammer to revive the eggs into talking creatures. These creatures when they were in danger could... evolve I suppose... into larger creatures to protect them.

It sounds (and was) pretty crappy but I think it was on Cartoon Network.

Answer (score 6):

[*Flint The Time Detective*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flint_the_Time_Detective) (aka: *Space-Time Detective Genshi-kun*, 1999).

> It involved a time travelling... buggy manned by a caveman,

Flint is a Time Detective who was resurrected from a prehistoric fossil. I don't know what you're considering a "buggy". He's got a little vehicle of sorts, but not what *I* think of when I hear the word "buggy".

> who went in search of monster... eggs in each episode.

His job was to go back in time and convince time-shifters to join him. He seems to find them in egg-shaped fossils.

> He'd then use this hammer to revive the eggs into talking creatures.

He has a sentient hammer which acts as a weapon and adviser.

> These creatures when they were in danger could...evolve I suppose... into larger creatures to protect them.

The Time-Shifters evolve into either an good or evil larger form.

> It sounds (and was) pretty crappy but I think it was on Cartoon Network.

I can't find exactly which channel it was on, but it apparently aired from March until November, 2000. There *was* a big anime push on Cartoon Network around that time.